# Python: Iterating a string with an int(variable) through a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, iteration

I'm an absolute beginner and have read many related topics but I just can't get my mind around it.

I try to create a function which iterates through the string s exactly "n" times.

```
s="hello"
n=2
```

If I simply type in

```
s[::n]
```

it does work, however, if I try to express this in a function everything goes haywire.

My function looks like this:

```
def printEvery(s,n):
    for n in range(len(s)):
        print(s[::n])
```

ValueError: slice step cannot be zero

I really don't get why it doesn't work in a function as in my head it only makes sense this way. I'd deeply appreciate any help.

E: Sorry for the format and thank you for the edit **khelwood**!

Comment: `range` starts at 0, you cannot slice a string to return every zero-th element.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this function draws a graph for the plot `len(str) * n ^ -1`. `printEvery('a'*206,None)` is great on a 1680x1050 monitor, using windows maximised python command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def printEvery(s,n):
    for x in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        print(s[::n])
printEvery("Hello", 2)
```

Not quite sure why you would ever need this though

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Miggl i am curious, what do you need this for?

Comment: It was a task for a beginner course on programming at my university

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in the comment, `range` starts at 0, so you cannot slice a string to return every zero-th element.

Another problem with your function is, that the parameter "n" is immediately overwritten by the `for` loop, so no matter with what second argument you call `printEvery`, it will always print the same text. This is equivalent:

```
def printEvery(text):
    for stepsize in range(1, len(text)):
        print(text[::stepsize])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def printEvery(text):
    for i in range(len(text)+1,1,-1):
        print (text[::i])
```

Every for loop starts at 0

Range's instruction is

```
range([start], stop[, step])
```

in which it indicates that where should the number start, then when should it stop and how many steps should it undergo.

In this case, it starts at 11, as I wrote len(text)+1 and I supposed len(text) is 10. I told Python to stop when it reachs 1, and each time it is -1 each time so if you replace

```
print (text[::i])
#replace this line to this:
print i
```

This would be printed:

```
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I hope it works for you. I am not really good at English so sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Thank you so much, dude! :)